# How to connect dialog to any qlineedit?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I have developed a virtual keyboard to input data into various qlineedits in a tester gui. My question is how, if possible, to use focusinevent or another method to launch the keyboard without modifying the gui's qlineedit?

Answer (score 0):

I think your have to check what would your like to use it.

The [**`QLineEdit`**](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html) or all class have API to used.

**In some method your can** call directly with out override. Such as `QLineEdit.setText (self, QString)`, `QLineEdit.setEchoMode (self, EchoMode)`, etc.

**But some method can't** call directly. Your have to override i. Such as `QLineEdit.dragEnterEvent (self, QDragEnterEvent)`, `QLineEdit.focusInEvent (self, QFocusEvent)`, anything have name `Event`, etc.